# 'MessageChannel is undefined' triggered on pages with reCaptcha v2

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, jsdom

I'm currently trying to scrape some sites that have recaptcha implemented, but whenever i load the page's source i get this error:
`(node:15536) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: MessageChannel is not defined`.

I have tried to implement the fix here: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2448#issuecomment-536242756, but it still throws the error.

Here is my code:

```js
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const request = require('request');

const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

const url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo';

function getPage() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request.get(url, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
        else {
            resolve(body);
        }
    }
    });
}

(async() => {
    const dom = new JSDOM(await getPage(), {
        url,
        contentType: 'text/html',
        runScripts: 'dangerously',
        resources: 'usable',
        pretendToBeVisual: true,
        beforeParse(window) {
            window.MessageChannel = require('worker_threads').MessageChannel;
        }
    });
})();
```

Thanks in advance,

iLinked

Comment: Are you passing `node` the `--experimental-worker` flag?

Comment: I've tried. even if i add it, it still throws the error

Comment: And just to make sure it's clear: it works fine when i try to eval 'new MessageChannel()'. It only gives me the error in the context of a ReCaptcha v2.

Answer (score 0):

MessageChannel is not available in the iframe context.

`beforeParse` functions won't run in frames: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2920